# splitting line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data of the below mentioned form:

```
<a> <b> <c> <This is a string>
<World Bank> <provides> <loans for> <"a Country's Welfare">
<Facebook> <is a> <social networking site> <"Happy Facebooking => Enjoy">
```

Now I want to split each line given above based on the delimiter <>. That is I want to split as:

```
['<a>', '<b>', '<c>', '<This is a string>']
['<World Bank>', '<provides>', '<loans for>', '<"a Country\'s Welfare">']
['<Facebook>', '<is a>', '<social networking site>', '<"Happy Facebooking => Enjoy">']
```

I tried splitting based on space and "> " but it does not work. Is there some other way in python by which I may split in the manner described above. Since my file size is 1 TB therefore I can not do so manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to split on the whitespace *between* the `>` and `<` characters. For that you need a regular expression split with look-behind and look-ahead assertions:

```
import re

re.split('(?<=>)\s+(?=<)', line)
```

This splits on any whitespace (`\s+`) that is preceded by a `>` and followed by a `<` character.

The `(?<=...)` expression is a look-behind assertion; it matches a *location* in the input text, namely anywhere the pattern inside the assertion precedes the location. In the above it matches anywhere there is a `>` character just before the current location.

The `(?=...)` expression works just like the look-behind assertion, but instead looks for matching characters *after* the current location. It is known as a look-ahead assertion. `(?=<)` means it'll match to any location that is followed by the `<` character.

Together these form two anchors, an the `\s+` in between will only match whitespace that sits between a `>` and a `<`, but *not those two characters themselves*. The split breaks up the input string by removing the matched text, and only the spaces are matched, leaving the `>` and `<` characters attached to the text being split.

Demo:

```
>>> re.split('(?<=>)\s+(?=<)', '<a> <b> <c> <This is a string>')
['<a>', '<b>', '<c>', '<This is a string>']
>>> re.split('(?<=>)\s+(?=<)', '''<World Bank> <provides> <loans for> <"a Country's Welfare">''')
['<World Bank>', '<provides>', '<loans for>', '<"a Country\'s Welfare">']
>>> re.split('(?<=>)\s+(?=<)', '<Facebook> <is a> <social networking site> <"Happy Facebooking => Enjoy">')
['<Facebook>', '<is a>', '<social networking site>', '<"Happy Facebooking => Enjoy">']
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you also explain as to what does the regular expression "(?<=>)\s+(?=<)" mean?

Comment: This is exactly what I was writing. Hell, even the description is almost exactly the same as mine. :-p

Comment: I mean I am new to python and I really want to learn as to how can I write such regular expressions. Therefore can you please explain

Comment: @IshaKhosla  this is the bestest re explanation page I have found: [link]http://flockhart.virtualave.net/RBIF0100/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sort of "build your own parser" approach, which just goes through the file character-by-character, and doesn't use any fancy regex features:

```
def tag_yielder(line):
    in_tag = False
    escape = False
    current_tag = ''
    for char in line:
        if in_tag:
            current_tag += char
            if char == '>' and not escape:
                yield current_tag
                current_tag = ''
                in_tag = False
            if char == '=':
                escape = True
            else:
                escape = False
        else:
            if char == '<':
                current_tag = '<'
                in_tag = True

for line in open('tag_text.txt'):
    print([tag for tag in tag_yielder(line.strip())])
```

Output:

```
['<a>', '<b>', '<c>', '<This is a string>']
['<World Bank>', '<provides>', '<loans for>', '<"a Country\'s Welfare">']
['<Facebook>', '<is a>', '<social networking site>', '<"Happy Facebooking => Enjoy">']
```